# Multiple return in function not working

Tags: javascript

I have many function inside one main function `validate` which doesn't work for some reason.However if the function `validate` contain a single function it works

```
function validate() {
   return textcheck("txtname");   
   return numcheck("txtnum"); 
  // textcheck and numcheck function are here 
 //doesn't work
}



function validate() {
   return textcheck("txtname");// works fine 
}


  function validate() {
   return numcheck("txtnum"); // works fine 
 }
```

why does 2 return inside a function don't work

Answer (score 4):

## Why it doesn't work

`return` exits a function, so code after the first `return` will never run.

Consider these functions:

```
function logs() {
  console.log('I have been called');
  return;
}

function doesNotLog() {
  return;
  console.log('I will not be called');
}
```

The first function does log a message to the console because `console.log` is called before `return`.

The second function doesn't, because `return` exits the function before `console.log` is called.

## Fixing your example

If you want to return `true` if **both** `textcheck` and `numcheck` return a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), you could use the logical AND operator `&&`:

```
// Returns true if both checks pass
function validate() {
   return textcheck("txtname") && numcheck("txtnum"); 
}
```

If you need **either** of the two tests to pass, use the OR operator `||`:

```
// Returns true if either check passes
function validate() {
   return textcheck("txtname") || numcheck("txtnum"); 
}
```

If you want to return the status of each individual check, you could return an object:

```
function validate() {
   return {
     textCheck: textcheck("txtname"),
     numCheck: numcheck("txtnum")
   }
}
```

Comment: Return array of values in the return expression

Comment: @joews thanks for the object method...didn't know that

Answer (score 2):

`return` exits the function when it's encountered, so your second `return` will never be reached.

If your goal is to return a truthy value* if **either** of two function calls returns a truthy value, you can use `||`:

```
function validate() {
   return textcheck("txtname") || numcheck("txtnum"); 
}
```

That calls `textcheck` and, if it returns a truthy value, returns that value; if `textcheck` returns a falsey value, it calls `numcheck` and returns its result.

If you want to return a truthy value if **both** of two functions returns  a truthy value, you can use `&&`:

```
function validate() {
   return textcheck("txtname") && numcheck("txtnum"); 
}
```

That calls `textcheck` and, if it returns a *falsey* value*, returns that value; otherwise it calls `numcheck` and returns its result.

---

I suggest working through some basic JavaScript tutorials.

---

* "truthy value" and "falsey value": JavaScript's `&&` and `||` operators don't always result in `true` or `false` like they do in many other languages. Instead, they look for "truthy" values (values that coerce to `true`) or "falsey" values (values that coerce to `false`). The falsey values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`; the truthy values are everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Return in function terminate him. 
If you want to validate two (or more) values use one return statement.

```
function validate() {
    return textcheck("txtname") && numcheck("txtFname"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution may help you if you need to return 2 values at the same time. You just need to return a json object

```
function validate() {
   return {
      txtname : textcheck("txtname"),
      txtnum : numcheck("txtnum")
   }
}
```

After you call the function, you can get your values like this :

```
var result = validate();
// result.txtname 
// result.txtnum
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I assume you want the validate() return you success (true) if both textcheck() and numcheck() succeed. Try this -

```
function validate() {
   return textcheck("txtname") &&  
          numcheck("txtnum"); 
}
```